# Evaluating ajax data forcefully as XML in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "something.html",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:function(data){} ,
  });
```

The content while accessing "something.html" is an XML but the above call is failed where if I use "something.xml" it is working fine.

Is it possible to make jQuery to forcefully evaluate the data as XML, without worrying about the file extension?

Comment: What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: When the above code is executed error callback is invoked. :(

Comment: You can override that by monkey-patching but it may lead to other complications all you have to do is make sure MIME type is text/xml it will work fine

Comment: problem is, I need this to work with a crude server the client code from scratch... some bull***t :(. I was wondering if there is some what to do it jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the file extension but with the MIME type your server is sending. jQuery expects as per dataType Setting that your server is going to send response as **text/xml** whereas your server might be sending MIME **text/html** so its throwing error as kgiannakakis pointed out.

Comment: is there a way to override this MIME checking in jQuery?

Comment: @Saneef you can override the MIME by using this code:
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the dataType option is used to define the expected type of data. Extension is irrelevant. The MIME header will be used when no dataType is set.