# (AJAX) get xml through a javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have got an issue by retrieving a XML through a javascript into Ajax. The problem is, it takes up to 45 seconds until the script collectes the data from the database and give it back as a xml. My code doesn't works anymore then. When loading the data local it works fine. Any ideas ? No cross-domain issue here!

```
//Get XML Data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://.../export.jsp',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml_list) {
```

Comment: What's the question? Do you want to reduce the load time, or do you want to make `$.ajax` not throw an error?

Comment: ahh sry... it is not working... it just loading without any end. Do I miss something ? Is it possible to get otherwise an exception or a timeout message ?

Comment: Yes, `$.ajax` has a `timeout` parameter. Do you have an error handler, or did you just not notice it already timed out?

Comment: On the webserver I can see that the request for the xml is done and transmitted. I am new to ajax, jquery so I dont know about the error handler, is this right: error: function(jqXHR, exception) { What types of errors can I catch ? Is there a nice site for that one? Thx in advance

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Just `alert` or `console.log(exception)` should be enough as a start. Have a look at [the Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)!

Comment: Just a quick question, the success will be only called when the url returns the correct datatype, even though it take a while ?

Comment: No, jQuery is quite liberal about the datatype; you can overwrite the server-sent MIME type with the `dataType` parameter as well. Of course, if the wrong assumptions were made, you'd end up with a parse error - in the error callback, so no success would be called, and you can easily check that.

Comment: Hi there, I included an error handler and now I am getting a parsererror on my page when trying to get the xml from the script. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check a) if you are really loading the correct url (the network inspector will help) and b) if you really serve valid XML (the parseerror message should help).

Comment: I am definitely loading the right URL and the parsererror says Requested JSON parse failed.
 error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
   console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
   showError('an unknown error occurred while trying to fetch the feed: ' + xhr.status);
  }
Might it be that there is no content header in the xml ?

Comment: JSON parse? Strange. Could you make a demo and link to that (or a sample URL of your XML file)?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
-<houseweb ms="0000" date="18.12.2012"> -<veranstaltung id="553"> -<titel>
<![CDATA[Theaterteller im xxxxx]]>
</titel>

Comment: Could it be that this issue is related to my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637734/evaluating-ajax-data-forcefully-as-xml-in-jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

It just sounds like your JSP script is responding slowly with your database. That's even more apparent when you say having the data local is fine. I would check your JSP script and also check slow query logs for your database to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi there, I included an error handler and now I am getting a parsererror on my page when trying to get the xml from the script. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? It could be that the response data is not what the JS is expecting. Maybe bad content type or something to that effect.